# statusCode should be 200, but is 415

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, http, http-status-code-415

I am trying to post a simple string, but I continuously getting the HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type Error. I tried converting the parameter to JSON still it didn't work.

**Method Updated**

```
func requestUsingPostMethod(url: String, parameter: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: [String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {

    //@escaping...If a closure is passed as an argument to a function and it is invoked after the function returns, the closure is @escaping.

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = parameter


    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [postString])
      //  request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { Data, response, error in

        guard let data = Data, error == nil else {  // check for fundamental networking error

            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {  // check for http errors

            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print(response!)
            return

        }

        let responseString  = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
        completion(responseString)


    }

    task.resume()

}
```

**Request**

```
NetworkCall().requestUsingPostMethod(url: "http://192.168.50.119:8181/rest/items/wemo_lamp_switch", parameter: "ON", completion: { response in

            print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
            print(response)
           // let jsonResults = JSON(String: response)
        })
```

**ERROR**

> statusCode should be 200, but is 415  { URL:
>   http://192.168.50.119:8181/rest/items/wemo_lamp_switch } { status
>   code: 415, headers {
>       "Content-Length" = 282;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json";
>       Date = "Tue, 12 Sep 2017 08:33:16 GMT";
>       Server = "Jetty(9.2.19.v20160908)"; } }

I Updated the question with your answers but still getting the same error.

**Postman Data**

```
{
    "id": "6f5d4f8a-612a-10f9-71b5-6dc8ba668885",
    "name": "simpledata",
    "description": "",
    "order": [
        "65df8736-1069-b0f0-3a1d-c318ce1810e0"
    ],
    "folders": [],
    "folders_order": [],
    "timestamp": 1505208950131,
    "owner": 0,
    "public": false,
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": "65df8736-1069-b0f0-3a1d-c318ce1810e0",
            "headers": "",
            "headerData": [],
            "url": "http://192.168.50.119:8181/rest/items/wemo_lamp_switch",
            "queryParams": [],
            "pathVariables": {},
            "pathVariableData": [],
            "preRequestScript": null,
            "method": "POST",
            "collectionId": "6f5d4f8a-612a-10f9-71b5-6dc8ba668885",
            "data": [],
            "dataMode": "raw",
            "name": "http://192.168.50.119:8181/rest/items/wemo_lamp_switch",
            "description": "",
            "descriptionFormat": "html",
            "time": 1505208951279,
            "version": 2,
            "responses": [],
            "tests": null,
            "currentHelper": "normal",
            "helperAttributes": {},
            "rawModeData": "OFF"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: 415 is for "Unsupported Media Type" . You may need to add to `request` the accept content-type to "application/json"?

Comment: You are sending a String to a WS waiting for JSON

Answer (score 3):

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Also

```
let theparam = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter)
```

Comment: hy tnx. even after adding that. am getting the same error.

Comment: @"application/json; charset=UTF-8" try adding the encoding also

Answer (score 0):

Set your request's `Content-Type` header to whatever you expect your API to return. If you're sure that it returns a `JSON` then

```
request.allHTTPHeaderFields["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```

Comment: hy tnx. even after adding that. am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a UTF8 encoded String instead of a JSON to the API, hence HTTP error 415. However, a simple String cannot be converted to JSON, it either needs to be part of an array or a dictionary, so you need to figure out the actual format your API is expecting.

`request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [postString])`

You might also need to add the `Content-Type` header to your HTTP headers.

`request.allHTTPHeaderFields["Content-Type"] = "application/json"`

Comment: hy tnx. even after adding that. am getting the same error.

Comment: Have you actually managed to get your API to work from any other platforms? You should first make the request work from a testing platform (such as Postman) and include the working request in your question. It really seems like, you don't actually know what format your API is expecting.

Comment: @David.tnx. I tried with postman as a raw data. it works fine. updated my question with postman data, please check.

Comment: @SathyaBaman is that the body of your request or the response headers? You should include any headers you used in Postman, the full URL including any query parameters if used and the request body in your question.

Comment: @"application/json; charset=UTF-8" try adding the encoding also